# C# - Allowing network folder access without enabling user access via Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, networking

I have an application that needs read/write access to a network folder that the user doesn't (and shouldn't) have access to. I am able to access the folder using several different methods including
NetworkCredential via System.Net and 
WNetAddConnection2 via the DllImport("mpr.dll")

No matter what method I use, when the application accesses the folder, the user is able to browse to the folder via Window->Explorer, even though the user doesn't (and more important, shouldn't) have credentials to access that network folder.

Is there a way I can allow network access to a folder for my application without enabling access to that same folder for the current user via Windows->Explorer?

Once the application closes, the user no longer has access to the network folder (although this takes a minute or so).

Thanks,

Comment: No.  Access is access.  The only way you *might* be able to do it is to have your application access the folder via a different user account.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think the OP is already doing something of the sort, as access is denied after the program terminates.

Comment: If a user runs the application, he can do anything with it he likes. So the credentials the application is using, the user can retrieve/intercept them anyway from the running application. Does the application need direct access to the share. Because if it doesn't. perhaps a better solution is to let the application use a service and let the service talk to the share for the user.

Comment: But if the application impersonates another user, why would the logged in user gain access to the folder via Windows Explorer?  The OP does not say the user gains access by using the app, but rather at the Windows level.

Comment: I agree with @RolfHuisman.  I've done this sort of thing with a service run with the privileged user's creds.  The problem with a user running a program that needs creds as another user is that you have to embed the creds.

Comment: @Michael is correct. I am using different credentials in the application. A service is definitely an option, but I am just trying to get a quick fix to a problem.

Comment: @ Eric J. - that is basically what I am having a hard time getting my head around. The application gains access to the network share by passing credentials that are different from the user. Once the application has accessed the folder, the user is able to then access the same folder via Windows-Exploer, without ever getting prompted for credentials.

Comment: @Rolf Huisman - Service is certainly the long term solution, but this application is fairly large and has tons of legacy code and the file/folder access is spread throughout the application. Their current solution is to just grant any user full access to the network share, but this is totally wrong as they are granted access to files/folders they have no business accessing.

Comment: An other unorthodox solution could then be, to add the service to the file server and create a dedicated share on the spot, bound to the security of the user. This way the application has a clear share access using its own credentials. One can then crete a share which only contains the information that is needed for communication, blocking out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the program have different access than the currently logged in user, it must be run via different credentials than the currently logged in user.

There are a couple of ways to achieve this, none of which are particularly easy.

You could allow the program to run via and only via the Run as Administrator option, requiring an administrator to start the program each time it needs to be run.

You could write a program to launch your program via [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the user via the [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) argument. This will only work if your program knows the username and password of the desired account, and may present a security risk as this can be decompiled and read without proper obfuscation.

The next option is to create and install a windows Service which provides the read/write functionality your program needs via some form of IPC, such as a WCF service. This would allow you to set the Service up to start and operate as an administrator, while the program itself is able to run using user credentials.

Comment: I was probably unclear but I am providing different credentials. Regardless of how I have passed those credentials via the application, the user gains access to the network files/folders via Windows Explorer, without ever being prompted for credentials.

Comment: If you're passing credentials via methods, you may be experiencing an edit to the current user's permissions, rather than truly running the application under different credentials.

Comment: that seems to be the case. am going to try passing in the user credentials via ProcessStart that you suggested and see if that at least doesn't provide a temporary fix.